# How to monkey-patch a class in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to monkey-patch the class "Tumble" with the module "Tinder". But when I add methods to the class, they aren't inherited. Constants, however, are.

lib/tumble.rb:

```
class Tumble
  ...
```

lib/tumble/tinder.rb

```
module Tinder
  APP_ID = 1234567890

  # Without self
  def xyz
    puts 'bar'
  end
```

config/initializers/tumble.rb

```
Tumble.include Tinder
```

The app loads Tumble and Tinder and I can access APP_ID:

```
$ rails r 'puts Tumble::APP_ID'
1234567890
```

But Tumble didn't inherit the methods:

```
[~/tinder]$ rails r 'puts Tumble.foo'
Please specify a valid ruby command or the path of a script to run.
Run 'bin/rails runner -h' for help.

undefined method `foo' for Tumble:Class
[~/tinder]$ rails r 'puts Tumble.xyz'
Please specify a valid ruby command or the path of a script to run.
Run 'bin/rails runner -h' for help.

undefined method `xyz' for Tumble:Class
```

How do I patch Tumble to include these methods from Tinder?

Thanks :)

Comment: Try `Tumble.new.xyz`

Answer (score 2):

When you call `Tumble.foo` that's calling `foo` as if it were a class method.

Yet when you do `Tumble.include Tinder` that adds the module's instance methods *as instance methods of Tumble*.

So, your current code should work if you do `Tumble.new.foo`.

You can also make `Tumble.foo` work with `Tumble.extend Tinder`.

Comment: I tried this and no luck, still undefined. What actually DID work is I put all the code from the Tinder module into config/intializers/tumble.rb and renamed it from "module Tinder" to "class Tumble" and everything works as expected. Ugly hack, I'd like to do it the proper way if possible.

Comment: @PatrickC The proper way is described in this answer, either use `include` and `Tumble.new.foo`, or use `extend` and `Tumble.foo`. If this isn't working for you, the problem is elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Tinder
 def initialize
  # some code here
 end
end
```

Imagine that this above was the class that you wanted to monkey-patch. To monkey-patch it you only need to write (on any place that gets loaded) the class Tinder again with the code to be added like this:

```
class Tinder
 def some_more_code
  # does great stuff
 end
end
```

This is monkey-patch. Modules won't do monkey-patch. They extend functionality but in a different way.

Just be aware not to override any methods of the original class that you want to monkey-patch, unless, of course, if that is your goal.